# for loop outputting function not result

Tags: javascript

Hi Im learning Js so please be kind. I have just learned about functions or methods inside of objects.

Im trying to loop through this basic object and the last key 'calcAge' is a function that should output '30' as you can see from the console.log at the bottom.  But the for loop is outputting the entire function as its written. How can I get it to output 30?

```
let currentYear = 2021;
const myFriends = {
  firstName: 'Alan',
  lastName: 'Snape',
  job: 'teacher',
  birthYear: 1991,
  friends: ['geoff', 'dave', 'sean'],
  hasLicense: true,
  calcAge: function (birthYear) {
    myFriends.age = currentYear - this.birthYear;

    return this.age;
  },
};


for (let i in myFriends) {
  console.log(`${i} : ${myFriends[i]}`);
}

// firstName: 'Alan',
//   lastName: 'Snape',
//   job: 'teacher',
//   birthYear: 1991,
//   friends: ['geoff', 'dave', 'sean'],
//   hasLicense: true,
//   calcAge: function (birthYear) {
//     myFriends.age = currentYear - this.birthYear;

//     return this.age;
//   },
// };

console.log(myFriends.calcAge()); //30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get `30` while you are iterating your object, you should check the property value is a function or not, if it was a function you can call it to get the function result, otherwise you can log the value directly, like this:

```
for (let i in myFriends) {
  console.log(`${i} : ${typeof myFriends[i] == 'function' ? myFriends[i]() : myFriends[i]}`);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!  This is exactly what I was looking for,  checking to see if it is a function first.  I wasnt aware how to do this :D

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the `calcAge` function into something like this:

```
calcAge : function () {
    this.age = currentYear - this.birthYear;

    return this.age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through an object and try to access the value of a key, you are basically pointing to the value of the key, and nothing more. You can observe that the values are correctly printed that are non-function or those that do not require any further operation on them (i.e, Arrays, string, numbers). But when the value is a function you get the function printed as it is, because it is just pointing towards the function and not invoking it.
To get the result as desired, you can simply check if the value is a function or not. If it is a function, execute it, or else print as it is.

```
let currentYear = 2021;
const myFriends = {
  firstName: 'Alan',
  lastName: 'Snape',
  job: 'teacher',
  birthYear: 1991,
  friends: ['geoff', 'dave', 'sean'],
  hasLicense: true,
  calcAge: function (birthYear) {
    myFriends.age = currentYear - this.birthYear;

    return this.age;
  },
};


for (let i in myFriends) {
  if(typeof myFriends[i]==='function'){ //Check if the value is a function.
    console.log(`${i} : ${myFriends[i]()}`); //Execute the function.
  }
  else{
    console.log(`${i} : ${myFriends[i]}`); //Print the value directly if it is not a function.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thakyou,  This happened because i was not aware how to post code snippets properly.  I have updated my question thankyou!

Comment: Thankyou for this. So much to learn and Im so happy I can actually look at what you have done and understand it haha. a month ago it would have been gibberish to me

Answer (score 0):

Your function is missing a value called `currentYear`. I added a function `currentYear()`. Now just invoke the function like so:

> ```
> myFriends.calcAge()
> ```

BTW there's no need to loop through the object, but I've altered it a bit to show the uses of `Object.entries()`, destructuring, and `for...of` loops.

```js
const myFriends = {
  firstName: 'Alan',
  lastName: 'Snape',
  job: 'teacher',
  birthYear: 1991,
  friends: ['geoff', 'dave', 'sean'],
  hasLicense: true,
  currentYear: function() {
    let now = new Date;
    return now.getFullYear();
  },
  calcAge: function(birthYear) {
    myFriends.age = this.currentYear() - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;
  }
};

let mF = Object.entries(myFriends);

console.log(mF);

for (let [key, val] of mF) {
  console.log(`${key} : ${val}`);
}

console.log(myFriends.calcAge());
```

Comment: Thankyou for this. So much to learn and Im so happy I can actually look at what you have done and understand it haha. a month ago it would have been gibberish to me